# Search bar xcode

Tags: ios, json, xcode5, searchbar

I have a new app for IOS where I'm parsing JSON and I'm using Search Bar. Parsing JSON works correctly, but I have problems with Search Bar, namely when I build my app and I want to search some words which were parsed I see nothing. Below I put my part of a code. I think a problem is with predicate :" predicateWithFormat:@"productName like[cd] %@", searchText];" Can anyone help me?

tableViewController.m

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"productName like[cd] %@", searchText];

    searchResults = [productsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}



-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
    shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{

    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]]; 
    return YES;
}




-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
       return [searchResults count];  
    } else {
        return [productsArray count]; }
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    Product *productObject;
    productObject = [productsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) 
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = productObject.productName;
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Cell" sender: self];
    }
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Cell"]) {

        DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;



        if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            destViewController.imageView = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        } else {

            //indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            Product * object =[productsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [[segue destinationViewController] getProduct: object];
            //destViewController.idLabel = [productsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is most likely with the predicate setup, as you suspect.

I'm using something like this for searching for matches in a list of contacts, perhaps it's a viable alternative:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(Contact *contact, NSDictionary *bindings){
    return [contact.name rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound;
}];
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have the same problem, when I compile my app, when I try to put some words in Search Bar nothing happened.It doesn't detect any names of my products import from base.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The issue wasn't in predicate but in cellForRowAtIndexPath: I made mistake in the second if statement, it should be like this:

```
Product *prod = nil;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

        prod=[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = prod.ProductName;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = productObject.productName;
        }
        return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  -(void)customizeSearchBar{
[self.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc]init]];

// Backgroud Color
[self.searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

// Search Bar Cancel Button Color
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[self.searchBar setSearchTextPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(10.0, 0.0)];

// set Search Bar textfield background image
[[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-bar.png"]
                                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// set Search Bar texfield corder radius
UITextField *txfSearchField = [self.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
txfSearchField.layer.cornerRadius = 14.0f;
txfSearchField.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeNever;
}
   #pragma mark - Search delegate methods

  -(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
[self.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
//    UITextField *txfSearchField = [self.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
//    [txfSearchField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
UIView* view=self.searchBar.subviews[0];
for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;
        [cancelButton setTitleColor:COLOR_RGB(250, 109, 40) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cancelButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_ROBOTO_REGULAR size:FONT_SIZE_13]];
    }
}
return YES;
  }

  -(BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
  [self.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
  return YES;
  }

 - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:   (NSString   *)searchText
   {
     if (searchText.length>0) {
       NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate  predicateWithFormat:@"department_name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    NSArray *arr = [self.arrData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    self.arrOperation = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr];

}
else
{
    self.arrOperation = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.arrData];
}
if(self.arrOperation.count == 0)
{
    self.imgNoDataMessage.hidden=NO;
   // self.imgNoDataMessage.image=IMAGE_NAME(@"instore.png");
}
else
{
    [self hideMessage];

}
[self.tblView reloadData];
}


 - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
UITextField *txfSearchField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
[txfSearchField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[searchBar performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(resignFirstResponder) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
     }

 -(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
self.searchBar.text = @"";
self.arrOperation = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.arrData];
UITextField *txfSearchField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
[txfSearchField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
if(self.arrOperation.count == 0)
{
    self.imgNoDataMessage.hidden=NO;
   // self.imgNoDataMessage.image=IMAGE_NAME(@"instore.png");
}
else
{
    [self hideMessage];
}
[self.tblView reloadData];
[searchBar performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(resignFirstResponder) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```